# displaying total textbox changed event in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to total textbox changed event in footer lable but my problem is last row value not calculate in total please help me.

**Aspx Code:**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GrdBindDenomination" ShowFooter="true"   runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" CellSpacing="20" EmptyDataText="No Records Found !"
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Denomination" >
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="Value" runat="server" Style="float: left" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" Style="float: left" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:TextBox   AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ID="TxtQuantity" OnTextChanged="TxtQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Text="0" Style="width: 140px;height:25px; float: left" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Style="color: red" ValidationGroup="a" ID="requiredfieldvalidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtQuantity"
                                                            ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server"  Style="float: left" ></asp:Label>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                             </Columns>
                                         </asp:GridView>
```

**ASPX.CS Code**

```
protected void TxtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal temptotal = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow currentRow in GrdBindDenomination.Rows)
            {
                decimal TotalClosingAmttemptotal = 0;
                TextBox quantityA = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("TxtQuantity");
                string itemQuantity = quantityA.Text;
                Label Value = (Label)currentRow.FindControl("Value");
                Label Total = (Label)currentRow.FindControl("Total");
                 
                decimal grandTotal1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Value.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(itemQuantity);
                Total.Text = Convert.ToInt32(grandTotal1).ToString();
                TotalClosingAmttemptotal = Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(Total.Text));
                temptotal += TotalClosingAmttemptotal;
                

            }
            GrdBindDenomination.Columns[3].FooterText = temptotal.ToString();
            GrdBindDenomination.Columns[3].FooterStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            GrdBindDenomination.Columns[2].FooterText = "Total";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? You have empty catch block. So even if there is an exception you will never know...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes debug my code but row last value not calculate and display in lable

Comment: always display value last - 1

Comment: What did you observe in debugging? Is there any exception? Which part of the code assigns value to `row last value`?  Are you databinding the gridview in page_load event? Where in the code you have `-1` ? What value you have in `temptotal` when you debug the code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya debugging proper work value assign complete but display only last -1

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya gridview bind in page load and temptotal assign value proper display only last -1 value

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya footer work on textbox chenged event?

Comment: When you are debugging the code what value you got in `temptotal` variable? Can you also share code of `page_load` ?..

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 BindDenomination();
            }

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this code working fine onrowdatabound but not working in textbox chenged event only

Comment: onrowdatabound not working? then you should share that code... how can we guess where is the issue?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya onrowdatabound working fine

Comment: Let me ask you again, When you are debugging the code what value you got in `temptotal` variable

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya temptotal value is proper but not display last row value in footer lable

Comment: Do you see `Total` in `Columns[2].FooterText` ?

Comment: only Total text Print on column 2 in Gridview

Comment: Found solution for your problem... you should use following code to set total value in the footer... `GrdBindDenomination.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = temptotal.ToString(); GrdBindDenomination.FooterRow.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left; GrdBindDenomination.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = "Total";`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya good work bro, Thank you